# AWK - how to change content in multiple files, in multiple directories

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am not a scripter, very much a beginner. I am going to remove text from *.bat files from over 1950 directories. I have the right command from removing the part of the files that I need, and I can copy these to a new output file (to not overwrite the old structure).

Example:

```
bin\awk "/^:COMMANDS/,0" F1\kits\test\engine\blah.bat > F2\kits\test\engine\blah.bat
```

It is tested and does the job.

Now I want to do this on all other files in the remaining 1949 directories.

So in theory this is what needs to be done:

```
bin\awk "/^:COMMANDS/,0" F1\kits\test\engine\blah.bat > F2\kits\test\_engine\blah.bat
bin\awk "/^:COMMANDS/,0" F1\kits\test1\engine\blah.bat > F2\kits\test1\engine\blah.bat
bin\awk "/^:COMMANDS/,0" F1\kits\test2\engine\blah.bat > F2\kits\test2\engine\blah.bat 
bin\awk "/^:COMMANDS/,0" F1\kits\test3\engine\blah.bat > F2\kits\test3\engine\blah.bat
bin\awk "/^:COMMANDS/,0" F1\kits\test4\engine\blah.bat > F2\kits\test4\engine\blah.bat
```

The changing factor is the directory (`test*`). But it would be very good if this could be done in a much more efficient way.

This is done on Windows (would prefer *nix...). How can I wrap this into a nice script?

Comment: Sounds more like you need to tag your question with whatever shell you use in Windows than awk. I use Bash in Linux and I would so something like: `for i in */*/*.txt ; do awk '{print FILENAME, $1}' $i > ${i%/*}/output.txt; done` (THIS WON'T WORK FOR YOU) to process files in subdirs' subdirs.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation :-) Ive updated with some more tags, but as written, Im extremely newbie... :-)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the input halfer. This was my first post on the forum.

Comment: Can you install cygwin and run your scripts in that UNIX-y environment? If not then get rid of the bash and shell tags and add WIndows....

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
for x in F1\kits\*; do y=$(echo $x | tr '\\' ' ' | awk '{print $3}'); echo $y; done
```

To see if you get `test`, `test1`, etc. If so then try your command:

```
for x in F1\kits\*; do 
    y=$(echo $x | tr '\\' ' ' | awk '{print $3}')
    bin\awk "/^:COMMANDS/,0" F1\kits\$y\engine\blah.bat > F2\kits\$y\_engine\blah.bat
done
```